# Prove by induction that $a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n}$

Tags: induction

I flip a fair coin $n$ times, the amount of possible outcomes is $2^n$. I'm trying to prove that the number of possible combinations that result in an even amount of heads after $n+1$ flips is equal to $a_{n} + a_{n}$

Outcomes with even amount of heads
$a_{0} = 1$
$a_{1} = 2$
$a_{2} = 4$

I thought about proving this by induction, but I get stuck right after the base case.

My attempt look something like this,

Prove that $a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n} $

Base case: We test if the condition is true for $n=0$

$a_{1} = a_{0} + a_{0} = 1 + 1 = 2$

The condition is true for $n=0$

Induction step: Assume that the condition is true for $n=p$ where $p$ is a positive integer.
Prove that the condition is true for $n=p+1$

$a_{p+1} =$

And this is where I get stuck...

Can I prove the condition true by induction or should I approach this in another way? Help is appreciated (:

---

**Edit**

Okay, I have redefined my question to something that I hope makes more sense.

I will try to prove that if I flip a fair coin $n$ times ($2^{n}$ possible outcomes), there is always $2^{n-1}$ possible outcomes with an even amount of heads.

The total amount of possible outcomes is $2^{n}$

Now, the condition I want to prove true is the following:

$n+1$ flips will result in $2^{n}$ outcomes with an even amount of heads. This is the same as saying that half of all possible outcomes will have an even amount of heads. But I can't know this until it has been proven.

I will attempt to prove this by induction.

I make the assumption that $n$ flips will result in $2^{n-1}$ outcomes with an even amount of heads.

**Base case:**
$1$ flip ($n=0$)

$2^{0} = 1$ The condition is true for the base case.

**Induction step:**

This is where I get stuck, not entirely sure on how to start it.

Comment: but why do you need induction?

Comment: What do you suggest that I use instead? It's not entirely clear to me how I can prove this

Comment: what $a_n$ do you use? $$a_n=2^n?$$

Comment: $a_{n} = 2^{n-1}$

Comment: I think you should use this idea. 'For every possible combination till now, there are chances of adding another two members - a head and a tail. So every combination has two forks and the number of possibilities become twice.'

Comment: Possible duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663971/prove-by-induction-that-a-n1-a-n-a-n

Answer (score 1):

Say that after $n$ tosses, you have $e_n$ even amounts of heads and $o_n$ odd amounts.

After one more toss,

$$e_{n+1}=e_n+o_n,\\o_{n+1}=e_n+o_n$$

because an even number can remain even or become odd, and conversely an odd number can become even or stay odd.

As $e_1=o_1=1$, $$e_n=o_n=2^{n-1}.$$

[Using your notation, $a_n=e_{n+1}=o_{n+1}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}=2^n$.]

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps look at this as follows: any combination of $\;p+1\;$ flips stems from a combination of $\;p\;$ flips after which you can get either head of tails, from which it follows that the total ammount is twice the ammoun of $\;p\;$ flips

Answer (score 0):

The induction step would be to say assume we have shown that $a_k=2^{k-1}$.  We want to prove that $a_{k+1}=2^k$.  As you have shown that $a_{k+1}=a_k+a_k$, you can say $a_{k+1}=2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}=2^k$.  That is the usual structure of an induction proof-you compute $a_{k+1}$ from $a_k$, substitute in the known value of $a_k$, and show $a_{k+1}$ is what you claim.

Comment: When did I show that $a_{k+1} = a_{k} + a_{k}$ ? It's correct but I can't know this until it's proven?

Comment: I thought I had seen that in your edit.  As Joanpemo says, you say the way to get an even number of heads after $k+1$ flips is to start with an even number of heads after $k$ flips and get a tail ($a_n$ ways) or with an odd number of heads and get a head.  For the second you have to argue that $a_n$ also gives the number of ways to get an odd number of heads.  You can define $b_n$ as the number of ways to get an odd number of heads or you can note this as a base case and subtract $2^n-a_n$.